# What is the answer to $ \log_5 (25\sqrt 5)$?

Tags: logarithms, fractions

I have started to do this question, but not sure if I am on the right track or not (or even allowed in math)

[image: work]

Can someone say if what I am doing is right?

Comment: It looks right, except it should be $\log_5 25\color{red}+\log_5\sqrt5$

Comment: $ \log(ab)=\log a+\log b$

Comment: It looks correct, apart from the typo mentioned by J. W. Tanner. A somewhat different way would be to combine the powers of $5$ before taking the log, e.g., $\log_{5}(25\sqrt{5}) = \log_{5}((5^2)(5^{\frac{1}{2}})) = \log_{5}(5^{\frac{5}{2}}) = \frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: oops yeah sorry about that haha, wanted to put in the log rule after that

Answer (score 1):

Yep your solution is correct except for the fact that you have multiplied when opening the logarithm. This is the correct identity **[log(ab)]=loga+logb** and not loga.logb

[image: The answer corrected]

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively:

$25= 5^2$ and $\sqrt 5 = 5^{\frac 12}$ and

$25\sqrt{5} = 5^2*5^{\frac 12} = 5^{2+\frac 12}=5^{\frac 52}$.

There are many ways to interpret this: $(5^{\frac 52} = \sqrt{5^5}=\sqrt{3125}=25\sqrt 5$ or $5^{\frac 52}=(\sqrt 5)^5 = (\sqrt 5)^2*(\sqrt 5)^2*\sqrt 5 = 5*5*\sqrt 5 = 25\sqrt 5$.

So all of this should make sense.

So $\log_5 25\sqrt 5 = \log_5 5^{\frac 52} = \frac 52$.